# Transition of a view with a slide?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I guess this has being asked before, but i couldn't find answer.
When i am replacing views, i would like that the first view,will slide from left to right (like a scroll view) .
But there is not option for that in the  `UIViewAnimationOptionTransition`

```
    UIViewController *mainV=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CallTestView"];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     [UIView transitionFromView:delegate.window.rootViewController.view
                        toView:mainV.view
                      duration:1.75f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         delegate.window.rootViewController=mainV;


     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{



                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by following way :

```
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[transitionAnimation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[transitionAnimation setDuration:0.5f];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[transitionAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeBoth];

[youView.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:@"changeTextTransition"];
```

you can replace or change direction according to your need in setSubType.